# Render Data from Fixtures in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to build simple ember application. I used the cache FIXTURES for rendering the data in template. But, I dont what am doing wrong in this template.

[Here is the example jsbin](http://jsbin.com/teliki/1/edit?html,js,output)

Template Code:

```
{{#each}}
      <option>{{mname}}</option>
{{/each}}
```

Js code:

```
 timeZoneApp.CalendarboxRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
       return this.store.findAll('calendarbox');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to actually define the route:

```
timeZoneApp.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('calendarbox', {path: '/'});
});
```

http://jsbin.com/tewelusewe/1/edit?html,js,output